# How to handle a question concerning a problem which "mutated" along the way?

Tags: discussion

What happened was I started solving a synchronization problem. Along the way I learned a better way to handle the whole thing and wrote my solution to the "mutated" question/problem, which was now somewhat disconnected from the original question/problem.

Here is the question in question:
[Syncronizing to NAS fails but works with USB disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768525/syncronizing-to-nas-fails-but-works-with-usb-disk)

Now, should I

- adjust the question to match the solution
- delete my own answer which is not directly answering the problem
- delete the whole question
- leave it be
- create a new accurate question and give my accurate answer there
- something else?

Comment: As you both asked and answered the question, I see no reason you should not just edit your question to fit your answer, it is a gray area when you answer someone else's question and the answer ends up removed from the question but in this case, it is all you, so edit as you see fit. Also don't forget to `format your code` with the {} option.